# How to change the color of the extension device blocks in Scratch 3.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockly, mit-scratch

I'm modding Scratch 3.0.

I have cloned `scratch-gui`, `scratch-blocks`, and `scratch-vm` and I have added my new extension device. Now I want to change the color of my extension device bocks but I didn't find any way to change the color of my extension blocks in [Scratch 3.0](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/?tutorial=getStarted).

Is there any way to change the color of the extension device blocks in 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

[scratch-vm Documentation](https://github.com/LLK/scratch-vm/blob/develop/docs/extensions.md)

```
            // Core extensions only: override the default extension block colors.
        color1: '#FF8C1A',
        color2: '#DB6E00',
```

Apply this color1 and color2 in getInfo()

```
class SomeBlocks {
constructor (runtime) {

    this.runtime = runtime;
}

getInfo () {
    return {
       
        id: 'someBlocks',

        // Core extensions only: override the default extension block colors.
        color1: '#FF8C1A',
        color2: '#DB6E00',
        .
        . 
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ScratchAddons? You can view their site here: https://scratchaddons.com/

Look for the "Customizable Block Colours" option.